# Errors when cross compiling GMP

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, gmp, mpfr

I have followed this [How-to](https://how-to-build-for-arm.wikispaces.com/gcc-4_8_2) and [g,h section of cross compiling tutorial](http://pmc.polytechnique.fr/pagesperso/dc/arm-en.html) for cross compiling GMP. This is the error message(last part) I get after running `make`.

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/arm/lib/libmpfr.so when searching for -lmpfr
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/arm/lib/libmpfr.a when searching for -lmpfr
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/arm/lib/libmpfr.so when searching for -lmpfr
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/arm/lib/libmpfr.a when searching for -lmpfr
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/arm/lib/libgmp.a when searching for -lgmp
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/arm/lib/libgmp.a when searching for -lgmp
/home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/xtools/build/final-gcc-cross/./mpc/src/.libs/libmpc.a(pow.o): In function `mpc_pow_exact':
/home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/xtools/src/gcc-4.8.2/mpc/src/pow.c:123: undefined reference to `mpfr_get_z_exp'
/home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/xtools/src/gcc-4.8.2/mpc/src/pow.c:135: undefined reference to `mpfr_get_z_exp'
/home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/xtools/src/gcc-4.8.2/mpc/src/pow.c:143: undefined reference to `mpfr_get_z_exp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [cc1] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/xtools/build/final-gcc-cross/gcc'
make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/xtools/build/final-gcc-cross'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is how I executed `configure`:

```
$ /home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/xtools/src/gcc-4.8.2/configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/arm --with-sysroot=/home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/arm/sysroot --enable-languages=c --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-multilib --with-float=soft --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-nls --enable-threads=posix --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --enable-long-longx --with-shared --with-gmp=/home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/arm --with-mpfr=/home/yogi/workbench/gcc-4.8.2/arm
```

How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: `file .../libmpfr.so`?

Comment: The links you give are about creating a cross-toolchain (using a native gmp), not about cross-compiling gmp.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I need to run a simple gmp program in android mobile. How to go about that? Sorry if the question is too naive.

Comment: First get a cross-toolchain (preferably with a gcc more recent than 4.8.2). This does **not** require a cross-compiled gmp, only a native one, which most system provide as a system package (for instance, install libmpc-dev on debian/ubuntu and forget about gmp/mpfr/mpc). Easiest would be to find a pre-compiled toolchain somewhere on the web. Once that is done, then you can think about cross-compiling GMP, passing --host=... to configure. But cross-compiling GMP before you have a cross-compiler doesn't make sense.